# Tensor product of distribution is continuous for each variable seperately

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $u,v$ be two distribution in $\mathcal{D}'(X),\mathcal{D}'(X')$:

given tensor product $$D'(X)\times D'(X') \to D'(X\times X')\\(u,v)\mapsto u\otimes v$$

prove tensor product is a separately continuous bilinear form on $D'(X)\times D'(X') $ [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2529418/360262)

The question here is what's topology on $D'(X)$ ,do we use weak topology?

I can only show sequential continuous result that is $u_n\to u$ in weak topology ,then $u_n\otimes v \to u\otimes v$ in weak topology.

How to show the continuous result does sequential continuous = continuous for $D'(X)$ with weak topology?

Comment: The topology on $\mathcal D'$ is the weak topology, i.e. $u_k \to u$ if $\langle u_k, \varphi \rangle \to \langle u, \varphi \rangle$ for every $\varphi \in \mathcal D = C^\infty_c$.

Comment: @md2perpe Hi,here is the point,for weak topology,**convergence** is characterized by this,but the point is why **continuous** of this bilinear map is charaterized by sequential continuous for weak topology?

Comment: You can read about the topology on $\mathcal D'$ in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Distribution_(mathematics)&oldid=992808742#Topology_on_the_space_of_distributions) of the Wikipedia article on distributions.

Comment: @md2perpe: before clicking on the wiki link I was expecting it to talk about the weak topology, i.e. the wrong topology, but wiki did the right thing and used the strong topology.

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam Hi do you have some reference book talk about theory of distribution under the assumption of Topological vector space .

Comment: There is no book I am happy with. Try this first https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-d-omega/3511753#3511753